# How to concatenate MKVs with different tracks

Tags: video, ffmpeg, codec, subtitles, matroska

I have an `mkv` film and a separate `mkv` with an introduction by the director. I'm trying to use `mkvmerge` to concatenate them. However, the film has subtitles and the intro has no subtitles, and this seems to be causing a problem.

Specifically, the track output from `mkvinfo intro.mkv` is:

`| + A track
|  + Track number: 1 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 0)
|  + Track UID: 1
|  + Track type: video
|  + Default flag: 0
|  + Lacing flag: 0
|  + MinCache: 2
|  + Codec ID: V_MPEG2
|  + CodecPrivate, length 164
|  + Default duration: 33.367ms (29.970 frames/fields per second for a video track)
|  + Video track
|   + Pixel width: 720
|   + Pixel height: 480
|   + Display width: 853
|   + Display height: 480
| + A track
|  + Track number: 2 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 1)
|  + Track UID: 2
|  + Track type: audio
|  + Codec ID: A_AC3
|  + Default duration: 32.000ms (31.250 frames/fields per second for a video track)
|  + Name: Stereo
|  + Audio track
|   + Sampling frequency: 48000
|   + Channels: 2`

and `mkvinfo film.mkv` gives:

`| + A track
|  + Track number: 1 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 0)
|  + Track UID: 1
|  + Track type: video
|  + Default flag: 0
|  + Lacing flag: 0
|  + MinCache: 1
|  + Codec ID: V_MS/VFW/FOURCC
|  + CodecPrivate, length 74 (FourCC: 0x57564331 "WVC1": VC-1)
|  + Default duration: 41.708ms (23.976 frames/fields per second for a video track)
|  + Video track
|   + Pixel width: 1920
|   + Pixel height: 1080
|   + Display width: 1920
|   + Display height: 1080
| + A track
|  + Track number: 2 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 1)
|  + Track UID: 2
|  + Track type: audio
|  + Codec ID: A_AC3
|  + Default duration: 32.000ms (31.250 frames/fields per second for a video track)
|  + Name: Surround 5.1
|  + Audio track
|   + Sampling frequency: 48000
|   + Channels: 6
| + A track
|  + Track number: 3 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 2)
|  + Track UID: 4
|  + Track type: subtitles
|  + Default flag: 0
|  + Lacing flag: 0
|  + Codec ID: S_HDMV/PGS
|  + Content encodings
|   + Content encoding
|    + Content compression`

I tried `mkvmerge -o full.mkv intro.mkv + film.mkv` but that gives me

```
Error: The file no. 0 ('intro.mkv') does not contain a track with
the ID 2, or that track is not to be copied. Therefore no track
can be appended to it. The argument for '--append-to' was invalid.
```

It's not clear to me from the man page for `mkvmerge` how to specify to `--append-to` that the intro track should just not have subtitles and the timecodes for the film subtitles can just be shifted. Is that beyond the capability of `mkvmerge`?

Perhaps I need to be looking into some other tool like `ffmpeg` to concatenate the audio/video from `mkvextract` and then some other tool to manipulate the PGS subs and them `mkvmerge` them all together again?

Am I going to run into further problems because the audio/video differ between the two files as well (e.g. stereo vs 5.1)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your problems are caused because the two videos are fully different, not (just) because of the subs.

> How to concatenate MKVs with different tracks

The quick answer is uncompress your audio tracks (to say, WAV), mux them (stitch them together) and then compress the audio (to say, AC3)

The best way to do this is to **convert** the soundtrack to uncompressed **WAV**, (to prevent out-of-sync), separately for each MKV-file.
Then concantenate and then recode them but don't recode the video stream, just the audiostream to a compressed format (MP3, AAC or AC3)

The above in steps:
1. Blow up the audio for each file, to an uncompressed format
2. Stitch them together.
3. Recode only audio to a compressed status

After 2, you should check if your audio is really sync.

You can do all of this with VirtualDub, or AviDemux 2.6.12 (set Video Output to copy), these are free and not malware.

> Perhaps I need to be looking into some other tool like ffmpeg to
>   concatenate the audio/video from mkvextract and then some other tool
>   to manipulate the PGS subs and them mkvmerge them all together again?

If you don't have denominational issues with Windows, rather than Linux, you could also convert your subs to ".SRT" format, and use that. I'm inclined to think it's easier to work with a text based format, than with a picture based format. Up to you.

> Am I going to run into further problems because the audio/video differ
>   between the two files as well (e.g. stereo vs 5.1)?

In general, YES!
The 2 audio tracks should have as identical characteristics as possible, so both stereo, this is the easiest because it's the most  universal. Don't use 5.1, unless you are in a theater.

Your videos should be the same width and heigth, so either **1920 x 1080** or **720 x 480**
My advice is to edit the shorter intro video. You can choose between:
- adding a border (but, it will be a tiny image)
- increase the width x height to **1920 x 1080** (but, it will be grainy)
- do **both**, half way, to split the difference. In your case this means:
a. increase the width x height to  **1440 x 640**
b. add a border of **240**  - (1920-1440)/2 - left and right and a border of **220**  - (1080-640)/2 to top  and bottom.